# OneDrive for Business Sync best practice

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

We are setting up our OneDrive environment for our users, but are concerned if they just use "sync" they will overload their personal computer's storage ability if the entire OneDrive library is synced(most of our users are data pack rats). I was able to test mapping a network drive to my OD4B folder but if I don't select "Keep Me Logged In" when I go to SharePoint then I lose the connection every time I reboot. Is their a way to map the OneDrive library and have it maintain a users credentials every time they reboot? Or is selective sync the best solution for this?

Those of you who are using OD4B, what choice have you used to have a local connection to your OD4B folder?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "Selective Sync" is not available in OneDrive for Business at this time. More people need to complain that it's not available. The best option as of now it appears is end-user training to not sync an entire TB to their local machine.

The other alternative as I mentioned above is to map to the library. This does require that every-time a user reboots they would need to re-login in to SharePoint and select "Keep me logged in". http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2616712

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to script Internet Explorer so that it will automatically authenticate users and refresh the authentication token so that your drive mappings are retained on reboot. There are a couple of Powershell scripts available in the community to do this. It looks like the licences permit you to customise them to your needs:

- [office365drivemap.codeplex.com](http://office365drivemap.codeplex.com/)
- [www.lieben.nu/numb3rs/?page_id=129](http://www.lieben.nu/numb3rs/?page_id=129)

If you would consider a commercial solution, then you could take a look at Zee Drive which manages the mappings and token renewal for you: [Map network drives to OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online document libraries - Reliably](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/)

Disclosure: Zee Drive is a tool that my organisation develops

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll  test out the scripts you provided and report back.